# 3 DropDownLists and GridView

Tags: asp.net, .net, data-binding, gridview, drop-down-menu

I'm using ASP.NET to build a form which has 3 DropDownLists and one GridView.
i want that the first DDL to take it's values from a DB using a sql query.

After i choose from the list, i want that the second ddl will display values from a DB using SQL query depends on what i have chosen in the first ddl and so on.

And every time i choose something from the DDL i want that the grid view will be updated correspondingly to the values i choose in the DDLs.

i used dataset to get value by query from the DB to the first DDL list (using object data source), but i have problems with updating the GridView by getting DataTable from stored procedure which get three values (from the DDLs).

Can someone help me please, or giving me a hint?

Comment: Have you enabled `AutoPostBack` for each of DDL, and subscribed for their `SelectedIndexChanged` event?

Comment: please upload some code for us to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you try to achieve is called **Cascading drop down lists**, and AJAX control toolkit has the required infrastructure for doing this (see [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx)).

However, you also have other options:

1. Setting the `AutoPostBack` attribute of your DDLs to `true` and double-click them, so that you get a `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler for them, and in those handlers, fill other DDLs and update your GridView.
2. Use pure jQuery ajax to get what you want to do (preferred method)